# Facebook API login page in iPhone displays huge webpage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I tried using facebook API but once i tried integrating it. I noticed that the login form which displays the login form of facebook is so huge that causes it not to fit the whole login window of iPhone.

Anyone have an idea how fix this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes have this problem. I don't remember exactly what caused the problem but I think the reason was the session or your Facebook API key. It would be better if you post some code because your problem may not be the same as mine

Comment: HI, I directly used the code below.

session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:nil secret:nil delegate:self];
 
FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dialog show];

could this possibly be the cause of lacking API key?

Comment: yeah, sure. I think so. You should always provide the API key